# Entity Framework : Querying parent by a property of the child collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

Assume following model

```
class Order()
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public List<OrderItem> Items {get; set;}
}

class OrderItem()
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

So I have an order that has 10 items, now I need to build a query that returns all `Orders` that have the ***last*** item in their collection property `Items` having `Name` equals to specific value. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you checked something like this:
      `YourContext.Orders.Where(order => order.Items.LastOrDefault()?.Name == "TestName").ToList();`

Comment: Tried, `LastOrDefault()` method can't be translated SQL query.

Comment: Can you do appropriate OrderBy and then use FirstOrDefault? I think FirstOrDefault translated properly.